# MariaDB DATE to text, which way?

Tags: mysql, date, mariadb, query-performance

When using MariaDB (MySQL) we want to turn a DATETIME into a readable DATE and know of at least the following methods, all of which produce the same output of date, but ... is there any actualy performance differences between these convertions, given that the conversation will appear on several columns of a large dataset

```
DATE(NOW())
CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
CONVERT(NOW(), DATE)
```

The database is on a network server, which is used by other users, so "trial and error" would not produce reliable results. I cannot account for anything that ther users are running on the database and/or any other network/server activity which may be happening at the same time. Making a local copy would provide more (but, not completely) stable result, but on our coporate devices, we cannot take database copies.

The question is specifically aimed at the difference between the four options and any others, which I may not have considered in terms of "is there any actual difference between them"

Comment: Test all these options on a large dataset and you will have your answer!

Comment: The database is on a network server, which is used by other users, so "trial and error" would not produce reliable results. I cannot account for anything that ther users are running on the database and/or any other network/server activity which may be happening at the same time.

Comment: create your local copy of the table and perform the test on a stable environment.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps my question lacks some clairty; I am not looking for a "trial and error" solution.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from setting up a local instance at test there

Comment: @Shadow ... except that we cannot install software onto our coporate devices and would be a breach of company policy to make an offline copy of production data.

Comment: You do not need production data. Just a big table with tons of arbitrary dates.

Comment: @Shadow and put it where? ... we cannot install software, like; software installations are blocked by the likes of group policy and MS Traps.

Comment: Any device will do, including your own. Or use the freebie time from any cloud provider. Use your imagination!

Comment: Plus if this a controlled enterprise environment, there must be some dev/test servers around where you can fool around a little bit!

Comment: @Shadow I understand and appreciate what you're saying, but I wasn't looking for guesswork, trial and error, imagination approach ... I was hoping that someone might know, factually, if there is a difference between the functions. I suspect that the DB engine has ONE date conversion with a number of overrides, which is not something that can be determined by the approches suggested in these comments.

Comment: Actually, trying is the real thing. At the moment all you have is somebody claiming that there is no significant difference between the various methods you listed (probably rightly so). However, there is no reference provided in the answer. So, how do you know it is the right answer? If you create a large test dataset and run your tests several times, then you can actually see if there is a difference. Obviously, this requires more effort on your side.

Comment: @Shadow duly noted

Comment: "would not produce reliable results" weakly says that there is no significant speed difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using functions like this will not have any significant effect on query performance if they show up in your `SELECT` clause. The differences are too small to measure: they are in dozens of nanoseconds per row at most.  Use the one that makes your query easiest for the next person to read, and don't look back.

`DATE_FORMAT()` yields a text string, though. You should avoid that one unless you want to control the exact formatting of your date in a report.

If they show up in your `WHERE` clause they may make it impossible for MySQL to use an index on a date column.  For example, this would hit your performance.

```
WHERE DATE(timestampcolumn) = DATE(NOW())    /* slow! */
```

That's slow because it has to evaluate the `DATE()` function on every row in the table.  The same goes for the other conventions in your example.

If you want to do that kind of filtering, do this instead.

```
 WHERE timestampcolumn >= DATE(NOW())
   AND timestampcolumn <  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If you have an index on `timestampcolumn`, this `WHERE` clause will do a range scan on that index, saving lots of work on your server.

Comment: Thank you for a constructive answer; I suspect that the database engine interprets the functions and the actual execution is the same for each.

Comment: @ Sean this is most certainly **not** the case! As it was pointed out in the answer, date_format() yields a string, not a date, so it must have a different execution compared to all other listed transformations. The results may look the same, but are not the same!

Answer (score 0):

No significant difference in performance.

But this should be faster than all of the ones mentioned:

```
CURDATE()
```

(If you need something other than the current date, see O. Jones' answer.)

Another point:  Any "constant" expression will be evaluated once for the query, not once per row.  This implies that all values of `NOW()` or `CURDATE()` will be identical throughout the query.

And it further points out the inefficiency of `DATE(column)` for a large table.

Comment: But not all date / time functions are constant, sysdate() always returns the current time.

Comment: @Shadow - Yes, `SYSDATE()` is the one non-deterministic exception.